# Access-Conrol-Allow-Origin on multiple files for cross-domain

Tags: php, header, http-headers, cross-domain

I've encountered that this does not work on multiple files when working with cross-domain. Anyone have any reason or am I doing something wrong? I was able to have it work on one PHP file (`mydomain.com/file1.php`) that I'm accessing from another domain (`hisdomain.com`). When I tried to access another PHP (`mydomain.com/file2.php`) from the same domain (`hisdomain.com`), it won't let me access my scripts in `file2.php`, because I already have

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

in `file1.php`. Is this coincidence? Should this not be the problem?

However, these files is in an actual hosting site. (e.g. `mydomain.com`). When I tried working in localhost (`http://127.0.0.1/file1.php` and `http://127.0.0.1/file2.php`) with `hisdomain.com`, `file1.php` and `file2.php` was working correctly with both having

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: If both `file1.php` and `file2.php` return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, this should not be a problem. Are you sure that `file2.php` includes this header in the response?

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes, I have it in the beginning of the script (at the top). I tested everything without changes except the hosting from localhost to the real domain back to localhost, and localhost did indeed work