# REST api GET with jQuery, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, rest

Here is all my code

Html:

```
<form name="test" id="test" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Hit ME" class="page"/>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
 $.ajax
  ({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https:// url",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer xxxx"},

    success: function (){
    alert('yay!'); 
    }
});
```

Result:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x260c6d0>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x260c7d0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x260c6d0>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x260c190>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

Now, when I inspect the element in the networks tab of chrome, I get "403 forbidden". Im guessing that my Authorization header is incorrect, but im not quite sure how to do it. Any tips/help?

Also what would I have to do to get the response JSON in the function() success: part?

Thanks!

By the way I have also tried this

```
beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer xxx"); 
    },
```

Error message in network console

```
GET (url) 403 (Forbidden) jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
XMLHttpRequest cannot load (url). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: To get the response:  `success: function (data) { console.log(data); }`

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately it doesnt solve the problem of my authorization not working and my request being forbidden. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Yes, 403 can mean that you have no permission. Try to read the api docs about how to send the credentials, or contact with the maintainer about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try something like this in your `beforeSend`:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxxx");
},
```

And as stated in the comment, to access your response you'd use:

```
success: function (data) { 
    console.log(data); 
}
```

Let me know how that goes. You might not be getting authorized correctly, so as `inf3rno` suggested, give the api docs a read through to see that you're doing it correctly :)

Comment: Still giving me 403 forbidden. I've connected with this token and link to the api before via php and a REST console, I'll double check

Comment: @k9b Hrm that is weird. No issues with CORS at all?

Comment: weird! When I enter the wrong bearer token it gives me 401 Unauthorized. When I enter the correct one it says 403 Forbidden. Any ideas? I know this resource is accessible as I'm accessing it right now through the REST console

Comment: @k9b Hrm that's actually really weird. Are there any api docs I could look at?

Comment: Unfortunately not, very sorry. Thanks for all the help I'll ponder this tonight and keep on workin on

Comment: not sure if it helps at all but I added an error message that I found in the google chrome network tools console. It seems as though for this resource outside access is not allowed? But I dont quite understand as I've accessed this resource from compileonline.com (via php) and it works, but it seems to give this error for jquery on both compileonline.com and jsfiddle (which I find easier to use)

Comment: @k9b That's what I meant when i asked about [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) :P?

Comment: haha yea sorry. My knowledge is so lacking I really had no clue so I kinda ignored it :P I guess I got there eventually. Any ideas for a "hack" workaround? Somehow suppressing the origin url. Just so I can demo this and then explain the problem will be so much better.

Comment: @k9b Do you have access to said api?

Comment: As in the ability to modify it?

Comment: Sorry my internet cut out. I found a stack overflow question about a way to start up chrome with someone having that exact error. Some privacy setting. On my phone atm but I'll post later. So in your opinion, is this cors problem something I should talk to my backend people about? Obviously if others need to query this resource in javascript they will have this issue also

Comment: @k9b Yes the backend will need to be modified. This should be added `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` - [***Read More***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717551/access-conrol-allow-origin-on-multiple-files-for-cross-domain)

Comment: Thanks a ton man. Id offer you a job right now if I could lol

Comment: @k9b All good mate :-) You never know, Our paths might cross in the future! Let me know how it all goes and if you need any more help!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems there was an issue in javascript thats not happening in php or any other language I try it with. If you go to Google Chrome and click on Network, then click on requests and copy the cURL request it shows up like this

```
curl 'url' -H 'Origin: http://fiddle.jshell.net' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' --compressed
```

For some reason As you can see from the Google Chrome Console error message above (in the bottom of my question), the code wasnt liking the -H 'Origin xxx' I removed that tag and it worked fine. Seems as though in the cURL request from javascript it adds an origin tag that isnt there in PHP